# Is there any way of viewing the View Controller Stack in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, stack

Is there anyway of viewing the View Controller Stack in Swift?

Hoping for some kind of array I can read or `println()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to roll some code to traverse the object graph, but here is a start.

1. First you will need the key window from [UIApplication's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/keyWindow) `keyWindow` property.
2. Next get the root view controller via [UIWindow's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) `rootViewController` property.
3. Finally, recursively inspect the contents of the resulting [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/childViewControllers)'s `childViewControllers` array. The contained view controllers may have child view controllers of their own.

Dumping the view controllers from the first `childViewControllers` property could work like this (this is off the top of my head and untested):

```
func dumpViewControllers(controllers:[AnyObject], level:UInt = 0)
{
    if controllers.count == 0 { return }

    for controller in controllers as [UIViewController]
    {
        for var i = 0; i < level; i++ { print '>' };
        println(" " + toString(controller));

        dumpViewControllers(controller.childViewControllers, level:level + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but it should do the trick ;)
Just call `recursiveViewControllersDescription()` on your rootViewController to get a string with a viewControllers hierarchy

```
extension UIViewController {
  func recursiveViewControllersDescription() -> String {
    return recursiveChildViewControllersLevel(0)
  }

  func recursiveChildViewControllersLevel(level: Int) -> String {
    var string = String()
    for var i = 0; i < level; i++ {
      string += "\t"
    }
    string += self.description
    string += "\n"
    for viewController in self.childViewControllers as [UIViewController] {
      string += viewController.recursiveChildViewControllersLevel(level + 1)
    }
    return string
  }
}
```